# How I Can Add Folder In Dashboard In ShrePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, performancepoint, dashboard-designer

I Use `SharePoint 2013`,`Performance Point Content`And `Dashboard Designer` For Create OLAP Report .
How I Can Create Folder In Dashboard  And Deployed My Dashboard Report In This Folder ?

Answer (score 0):

Every dashboard you create in dashboard designer is deployed as a folder and the dashboard pages are deployed into that folder.

Comment: OK Tanks.But I Want's This Folder(Every dashboard you create in dashboard designer is deployed as a folder) Move To Favorites Folder That Create Me.

Comment: What do you mean by "Move To Favorites Folder That Create Me"?

Comment: Hi.For Example I create Report In Dashboard Designer Namely 'Product'. The Dashboard Designer Create Folder Namely 'Product' in Dashboard Folder's And Me Create a Folder Namely 'Analise' The Manually In Dashboard Folder's And I Want Remove Product Folder's Into Analise Folder's.